# Ajax (jQuery) cross domain output -

Tags: ajax, jquery, cross-domain

As is such function doesn't support cross domain request

```
    function makeRequest(url) {

    var http_request = false;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
                http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        }
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }

    if (!http_request) {
        alert('Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
        return false;
    }

    http_request.onreadystatechange = function() { alertContents(http_request); };
    http_request.open('GET', url, true);
    http_request.send(null);
}

function alertContents(http_request) {
    if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
        if (http_request.status == 200) {
            receiveData(http_request.responseText);
        } else {
            alert("error");
        }         
    } 
}
```

so decided to use jQuery (with [this plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/)) but function

```
    $.ajax({
  url: suchurl,
  type: "GET",
  //dataType: "text",
  dataType: "text",
  //global: false,
  //async:false,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {

//alert(data);
alert(data.responseText);

}
});
```

output like

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 26 Sep 2004), see www.w3.org" name="generator"/>
<title/>
</head>
<body>
<p>new_towns = [ {id:"0", name:" "},
{id:"205",
name:"City205"},
{id:"17",
name:"City17"}
];</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Why?.. when expecting just

```
new_towns = [ {id:"0", name:" "}, {id:"205", name:"City205"}, {id:"17", name:"City17"} ];
```

**What you advice?
Thanking you in advance.**

---

such example code - doesn't work

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    google.load("jquery", "1.6.2");  

google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {

$.ajax({
  url: suchurl,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "text",
  crossDomain:true,
  async:true,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
  alert("all right");
  }
  });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**OK, guys, it's more simple and more fast&understandable decision use script
get.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['geturl']) and !empty($_POST['geturl'])) {
$data = file_get_contents($_POST['geturl']);
print $data;
}

?>
```

**and then just**

```
$.ajax({ url: 'get.php',
         data: {geturl: suchurl},
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: "text",
         cache: false,
        success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        //do something else

   }
 });
```

**TNX VERY MUCH FOR YOUR ATTEMPTS TO HELP AND TIPS!**

Comment: if you are expecting json data do `dataType: 'json'`

Answer (score 1):

I don't guess you need to rely on a plugin for getting cross domain JSON. You can use jquery's 'jsonp' dataType.

You can follow the 'JSONP' section in the following URL:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

The output you are getting may be something that the URL returns. Make sure the requested URL returns only the expected output.
Thanks

Comment: tnx, I'll be trying, by the way - if get result in browser by url and view code - nothing like ".... HTML Tidy for Java ...." , only correct "new_towns = [ ..."

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in your first example, you are requesting text/xml, but in the second one, your type is just "text" which might be causing the url to send back a differently formatted response. For JSON data, you could also try a type of "application/json".

Comment: if use $.ajax with dataType - json or jsonp - nothing happens ((

Comment: Sounds like a server problem, if it's not responding to requests for valid data types like those... Try a few other browsers, some handle ajax better than others, and if some work, that would eliminate the server as the problem.

Comment: If you can't get anything but the HTML version, you could actually parse that HTML in your success function and extract the part you want. Something like this: $(data).find("p:first").text();

Answer (score 1):

The JQuery `$.ajax()` function includes native JSONP support. You must add the parameter `crossDomain:true`

You can read about it here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Why are you setting async:false? Also you have a semicolon after your url string.

Comment: sorry, don't understand code, even with async:false - nothing, sorry add code in question body, thank you for your attention

Comment: no :( is it really need? what needs changing in example code (in question) - to propely work?